# Run background task when device starts

Tags: android, react-native, background

I'm looking for a way to perform some actions in my (android only) React native app when the device starts, so I tried with this library: https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task

...but there is no way I can make it without launching the app at first and then put it in the background. My mentor told me that it's possible but I can't find a way.

Is anyone having some tracks for me?

Thanks for your help

Comment: why don't you ask from your mentor directly  ^_^

Comment: Do a research on Boot Receiver permission and how to use it.. That might help you.

Comment: My mentor is not available right now. Thank you @Sivakumar, I think I got it

Answer (score 0):

The app must be launched in order to actually schedule the background task with the respective operating system. Afterwards it should continue to execute periodically even on restart of the phone, so long as the user has not manually killed your app (as this directs the OS to remove the task from the scheduler).

If you are processing jobs in your scheduled background task function, and you need them to persist across device restarts, look into [react native queue integration with react native background task](https://github.com/billmalarky/react-native-queue#os-background-task-full-example).

Hope this helps.